# Open new popup chrome window without tab section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, browser

Sometimes surfing the web with chrome,I encounter a website or web app,when click on an `<a>` or `<button>` element it opens a new popup browser window which does not have tab section while I do not have any Chrome Extension installed:

main window:

[image]

popup new window:

[image]

My question is,How to do this using JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","_blank",
    "toolbar,scrollbars,resizable,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Poor resource. parameters to open should not have spaces and no need to have =yes: `"toolbar,scrollbars,resizable,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400"` is better

Comment: w3schools is a poor resource?

Comment: Yes very. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) instead. As you can see you example is not correct

Comment: @mplungjan Why not? It works fine, also I prefer to have spaces, it is easier to read, why smash it all together? You can minify later.

Comment: Because it will break in some browsers. That is why: _strWindowFeatures
An optional parameter listing the features (size, position, scrollbars, etc.) of the new window as a string. The string must not contain any whitespace, and each feature name and its value must be separated by a comma._

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for the explanation, that is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="openTheWindow()">open window</button>

<script>
function openTheWindow() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=800,height=800");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Again: no spaces in the parameters: "width=500,height=500"

Comment: Spaces are allowed here and i added them to make it more readable

Comment: No they are not allowed between the options in the third parameter. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Return_value_and_parameters